# Run button to test function disappeared in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

When I used pycharm, there used to be this run option close to my function declarations which I used to run my tests. I opened my pycharm today and this option disappeared.
It used to be like in this pycharm tutorial:

[image: run option close to function declaration]

Now it is not there anymore:

[image: my pycharm now]

I can run the whole test file, but this option was very useful for me to test only one function. I don't know if I changed something, but I can't put it back.

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/testing-your-first-python-application.html), it seems possible that something happened with your test runner configuration. Did you try updating PyCharm, checking all the relevant test/test runner settings, and all that? Did you update Python or any libraries recently?

Comment: I didn't update anything. I tried uninstalling pycharm and installing again, cleaning the cache, removing and adding the project. I double checked the test runner settings, restored default configurations, everything I could think of